# how to replace the token in a string with the specified value in php?

Tags: php

Is there any function in php to performance like this:

_str_replace(hi %username, your password is %pwd, 'David', 'P@ssw0rd') will return the string "hi David, your password is P@ssw0rd"

Answer (score 5):

```
printf('Hi %s, your password is %s', 'David', 'P@ssw0rd');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/S4tPTjiy).

If you don't want it to immediately echo, use `sprintf()`.

Alternatively, you could make that function...

```
function _str_replace() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $str = array_shift($args);
    foreach($args as $arg) {
       $str = preg_replace('/%\w+/', $arg, $str, 1);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/wLbk4LP3).

...but I wouldn't bother. You can't refer to the variable by their original name within the function because that information is not sent to the function.

You could if you used an associative array...

```
function _str_replace($str, $vars) {
    foreach($vars as $name => $var) {
       $str = preg_replace('/%' . preg_quote($name, '/') . '/', $var, $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/tztDF9zE).

Alternatively, if you wanted to send the identifier inside of the associative array, you could replace it with function body with `return str_replace(array_keys($vars), array_values($vars), $str);`

Comment: I didn't know about sprintf elegant way to return a modified string the down fall is you must use their syntax so %username won't work

Comment: The syntax of `sprintf` and related functions is very old and made sense at the time. I think it still does.

Comment: It still makes sense you name based on type but if you are making a parser your html would look like 'hi %s your password is %s you can change your password by going to %s you have %s minutes until you must request again." or something like that which isn't really readable

Comment: @austinbv, the point is that the HTML *doesn't* contain `%s`, the format strings in the PHP functions contain `%s`, but they output values in which the `%s` is replaced by the other parameters. Things like `sprintf` weren't intended for the use you asked about.

Answer (score -1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is what you're looking for

```
$string = "hi %username your password is %pwd";
$string = str_replace("%username", $username, $string);
$string = str_replace("%pwd",$password, $string):
echo $string;
```

Comment: Alex's is better than mine if an echo is all you need mine is stronger if you need to modify the string more, mine is also better if you would like to define the values you replace with alex's you must use %s

Comment: put `%username` and `%pwd` between quotes in the first parameter of `str_replace`

Answer (score -2):

If the first portion of the string is static, why not just concatenate the variables? This may give you more flexibility.

```
$username= "david";
$password = "password";
echo "hi". $username . "your password is". $password;
```